# Exception occurred while connecting to wcf endpoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, security

I get very strange exception:

> "exception occured while connecting to wcf endpoint. Access
>   denied"

Only when I go to any Document Library.

I have logged as Administrator and I have added "Full control" Permissions for it on "User profile service application".

I have searched on Google but non of workarounds helped me to solve the problem. It is my developing envrionment and I have created a new web appliction.

Comment: Check your IIS and ULS logs to see if you can identify the specific error message on the backend.

Comment: I looked att iis log files couldn't find any strange there.

some days ago I run dsinit /sqlinstance :. to initialize storage for Windows Azure localy, I am wondering if it may changed some configurations.

Comment: What credentials are you passing to the WCF when you attempt to connect to it? Do you explicitly enter a username/password in the code, or are you telling the program to use your windows credentials?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might have something to do with SharePoint's IIS application pool user account ("Identity"). If you are using a user account that has no persmission set in central administration for the "User profile service application" then this error occurs.

To resolve the issue grant "Full Control" permission to your application pool user account:

- Goto service applications page in central administration
- Select "User profile service application"
- Click on button "Permissions" in the Ribbon
- Add the user account to list and then grant "Full Control"

Hope this was the causing of you problem. SharePoint configurations can be a real pain.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have alredady done it. and it didn't help.